# Connect a camera module with parallel camera interface to RPi

Tags: camera

I want to connect the MT9M001 camera module directly to RPi. The camera (chip itself) has a 10 bit parallel interface. Is it possible to connect such cameras to RPi without additional chips?

Comment: I skimmed the spec and found that you need a cam shield, either for Atduino or Rpi.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to connect the data bits and strobe to the GPIO and read in a 10 bit value at each strobe.

**If the Pi controls the strobe** you might be able to take a million or so 10-bit readings per second.  I'm afraid there would be no time to process that data though.  Assuming the data had to be processed in software I'd guess a maximum of a few thousand 10-bit readings per second.

**If the camera controls the strobe** I would estimate you have zero chance of using the device on the Pi.

Comment: I will take a look if it is acceptable to generate a pixel clock programmatically (and it means irregular), it will work like a strobe signal.